# Is TryGetValue thread safe with itself

Tags: c#, dictionary, thread-safety, trygetvalue

So, I've got a `Dictionary<KType,VType> Foo`

In one thread I have:

```
void Thread1() {
  ...
  if (!Foo.TryGetValue(key, out v)) {
    Foo.Add(new VType());
  }
  ...
}
```

The only time `Foo` is ever accessed by another thread is by a `TryGetValue`.

So, how much to I need to lock? Can I do something like:

```
void Thread1() {
  ...
  if (!Foo.TryGetValue(key, out v)) {
    lock (syncobj) {
      Foo.Add(new VType());
    }
  }
  ...
}
void Thread2() {
  ...
  lock (syncobj) {
    Foo.TryGetValue(key, out v))
  }
  ...
}
```

The Thread1 is 90% of the program computation and `TryGetValue` is called many times. So, preferably, I would like to not have to call lock every time.

Comment: There is this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx

Comment: Wow... I didn't find that on Google, and I was looking too. I guess everything I saw was pre-2010.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to `lock` every time if there's *any* chance that an update can occur on another thread at the same time a `TryGetValue` is being executed.

`TryGetValue` is thread-safe with *itself*, in that multiple threads calling `TryGetValue` won't interfere with each other. But if any thread calls `Add` while others are doing *anything* else with the dictionary, then there's the possibility of corruption.

That said, a lock might not be terrible. You say that `TryGetValue` is called "many times", but you don't say how often. More importantly, you don't say how often you're likely to get a conflict. An uncontended lock is going to cost you something like 50 nanoseconds on modern hardware, so it's not a *huge* expense. You might try the lock just to see how it performs. You might also consider a [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx).

It's important to understand that `ConcurrentDictionary` is not a lock-free data structure, although read operations are done in a lock-free manner. It *might* perform better in your situation (probably will), but that's not a given.

Comment: Nice to know, it was more of a question out of curiosity than necessity. I was sort of trying to justify the question with the "reason" of speed. `ConcurrentDictionary` seems to be the "right" way to do it. (At least its the more elegent way IMO).

Comment: In fact, a `Dictionary` is the example use case for [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx)